# How to check if a member function or free function is for the exact given type(not any of its base)?

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20, template-meta-programming

A way to check if a member function/free function can be invoked on an object would be to:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <class T, class = void>
struct HasMember : std::false_type {};
template <class T>
struct HasMember<T, std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().Foo())>> : std::true_type {};

template <class T, class = void>
struct HasFreeFoo : std::false_type {};
template <class T>
struct HasFreeFoo<T, std::void_t<decltype(Foo(std::declval<T>()))>> : std::true_type {};

struct A { void Foo() {} }; 
struct B : A {};
struct C : B {};
                                          
void Foo(const A &) {}

int main() {
  static_assert(HasMember<C>::value, "");
  static_assert(HasFreeFoo<C>::value, "");
}
```

But as what the example demonstrates,

1. `C` is considered to have the member `Foo` since `A` has implemented `Foo`,
2. `C` is considered to have the free function `Foo` implemented since `Foo` accept `const A &`.

What I want to achieve is to have `HasMember<A>::value == true && HasMember<C>::value == false`. `HasFreeFoo<A>::value == true && HasFreeFoo<C>::value == false`. Any help is welcome, thanks.

Background:
I am implementing a ser/des tool, user can choose to either implement a member function or a free function to specify how should a type get ser/des. And I need to check if such member function / free function are implemented (not inherited from its base) exactly for the given type .

Comment: It sounds a bit expensive, but can't you keep doing `dynamic_cast`s? It's not the most elegant perhaps ... Can you redesign your setup?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I don't see how dynamic_cast helps... Nothing is polymorphic here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The implementation of `HasMember` and `HasFreeFoo` is reasonable since `C` can indeed obtain `Foo()` through inheritance. What you need is to implement another trait to choose whether to invoke through the member function or the free function. For example:

```
template <class T, class = void>
struct UseMemberFoo : std::false_type {};

template <class T>
struct UseMemberFoo<T, std::enable_if_t<HasMember<T>::value && !HasFreeFoo<T>::value>>
 : std::true_type { };

template<class T>
void Foo(const T&) = delete;

template <class T, class = void>
struct UseFreeFoo : std::false_type {};

template <class T>
struct UseFreeFoo<T, std::enable_if_t<HasMember<T>::value && HasFreeFoo<T>::value>>
 : std::true_type { };
```

When `T` only has member `Foo()`, then invoke it through the member function. When the user inherits the base class which has member `Foo()` and provides the free function for the derived class, then invoke it through the free function.

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/q1W1s66Mq)

Comment: What if member Foo in the example is implement for C (instead of A)? Choosing the free Foo is not ideal.

Comment: @felix. This can be solved by defining a `delete` template `Foo()` function. When there is no free `Foo()` that accepts the exact type, the deleted template `Foo()` will be selected since there is no implicit conversion involved, resulting in `Foo(x)` being ill-formed, see updated.

Comment: @康桓瑋 With the deleted template, `HasFreeFoo` is able to checked if the free function is implemented for the exact given type. I will change my design and use free function entirely.